# Can't access to internet with my virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, centos, vmware-workstation, ip-address

I created a virtual machine (Centos) on VMWare workstation. The network adapter is on bridge.

My computer has the following IP address : `10.0.0.5/24` and the gateway is `10.0.0.1`,
so my virtual machine has the IP address of `10.0.0.50/24` on `eth0` interface.

I have only one road, it's my default gateway `10.0.0.1`.
Destination is `0.0.0.0` gateway - `10.0.0.1` and netmask `0.0.0.0`.

I can ping my computer but I can't ping the gateway and I don't understand this behavior. 
So after that, I can't ping `8.8.8.8` so I don't have any internet access. 
I can access my VM from my computer.

Could you please help me to find a solution to access internet? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does your physical machine have multiple interfaces? If so go in to the virtual network editor and verify that your bridge interface is set to use the correct physical interface.

Comment: Are you behind a firewall? Once I couldn't access the internet on a virtual machine, and eventually figured out it was a firewall.

Answer (score 2):

1. In the main menu of VMWare go to Edit -> Virtual Network Editor. In the listbox choose an entry which has Bridged type (or create a new one). Below in VMnet Information the Bridged option should be selected for that entry. Make sure that in "Bridged to" combobox the correct adapter is selected (should be your physical adapter which is used by the host).
2. Now go to the  Network adapter settings of your specific guest (VM -> Settings -> Network Adapter). In Network connection select "Custom: Specific virtual network option". Then in the combobox select VMnet# you previously set up in Virtual Network Editor.
3. Reboot you guest OS, see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Either use the type NAT or setup the network so 10.0.0.1 routes to your real gateway. 10.0.0.0/8 is a private network that does not route to the internet.